# Segmentation Fault on 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm making what we call an integral image, but I have a problem. When I reach a certain number I have an Segmentation fault. The image is 273*273 it works, 274*274 not working.
So i tried to Malloc my double array. Same.
I've read that arrays in a function are in the Stack, and the stack has small space. How can I make my array declared in the memory?

I am using C99 and SDL:

```
void integral_img(SDL_Surface * img)
{
    int **M;

    M = malloc(img->w * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < img->w; i++)
    {
        M[i] = malloc(img->h * sizeof(int));
    }
    int sum_int = 0;
    Uint8 sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < img->h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img->w; j++)
        {
            SDL_GetRGB(getpixel(img, i, j), img->format, &sum, &sum, &sum);

            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                sum_int = (int)sum;
            if (i == 0 && j > 0)
                sum_int = (int)sum + M[i][j - 1];
            if (j == 0 && i > 0)
                sum_int = (int)sum + M[i - 1][j];
            if (i > 0 && j > 0)
                sum_int = (int)sum + M[i - 1][j] + M[i][j - 1] - M[i - 1][j - 1];
            M[i][j] = sum_int;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare it outside of the function?

Comment: There is no 2D array! A pointer is **no** array!

Comment: memory declared using `malloc` will be on the heap, regardless of where it was allocated.

Comment: Your array is also not an array but a pointer.

Comment: Your allocation code seems to allocate `M[w][h]`, but the summation code seems to assume it's `M[h][w]`.

Comment: Where's the segfault?

Comment: You are using `malloc` which won't allocate from the stack, so that's not your problem. I noticed your double `for` loops may have `i` and `j` mixed up. Isn't `i` applying to width, and `j` to height? so the outer loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < img->w; i++)` and the inner `for (int j = 0; j < img->h; j++)`? Although that doesn't explain why h = w = 274 doesn't work...

Comment: While mixing up `i` and `j` is playing with fire, using a *square* image (`h == w`) should only produce unintended results, and not a segfault.  Fixing the order is worthwhile, but the source of the crash lies elsewhere.

Comment: Is it crashing inside `getpixel()`?

Comment: Your code leaks memory each time you call this function. Perhaps that is the reason for the crash.

Comment: Well i've tryned to mallox my array of size 1000*1000, worked.
I've changed i and j for img->h annd img->w same error :/

Comment: First, try with different sizes, for example w=10, h=20, then the other way around, w=20, h = 10,

Comment: It is working in a 10*10. But it is working now. Good I don't like C xD Thx guys ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are allocating a pointer-based lookup table, not a 2D array. It will work, but it is wide-spread incorrect practice: it makes the program needlessly slow for no gain. Consider using a 2D array instead:

  ```
  int (*M)[w] = malloc( sizeof(int[h][w]) );
  ...
  free(M);
  ```
- One bug is here:

  ```
  M = malloc(img->w * sizeof(int *));
  for (int i = 0; i < img->w; i++)
  {
      M[i] = malloc(img->h * sizeof(int));
  }
  ```

  Here you declare the inner-most dimension of your lookup table to be `w`, width.

  But later on

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < img->h; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < img->w; j++)
      ...
      M[i][j] = sum_int;
  ```

  you say that the inner-most dimension is `h`, height.
- Furthermore, your program leaks a lot of memory each time you call the function, since you don't free memory anywhere. In fact, you don't seem to even use the lookup table after filling it up.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of your code, modified to illustrate 2D array initialization *and* cleanup (you must free what you malloc):

In short, your array initialization has to follow the way you create memory for *row*, *column*:

```
typedef struct  {
    int h;
    int w;
}SDL_Surface;
//if you change your prototype to pass the initializer then you can
//free it in the calling function.  Otherwise, as written in your OP
//you will have a memory leak.
void integral_img(SDL_Surface * img, int **m);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Surface img;
    int **M; 

    img.h = 100;
    img.w = 50;
    //create memory for array in calling function
    M = malloc(img.w * sizeof(int *));
    if(!M){ /*handle error and leave*/ }//test results of malloc
    for (int i = 0; i < img.w; i++)//... If you create space for w rows and h columns...
    {
        M[i] = malloc(img.h * sizeof(int));// note modified prototype
        if(!M[i]) {/*handle error and leave*/} //test results of malloc
    }

    integral_img(&img, M);

    //use img...

    //free M :(no memory leaks)

    for (int i = 0; i < img.w; i++)
    {
        if(M[i]) free(M[i]);
    }
    if(M) free(M);


    return 0;
}

void integral_img(SDL_Surface * img, int **m)
{


    for (int i = 0; i < img->w; i++)//... Then you must access w rows and h columns
    {                               // (w & h were reversed in your code)
        for (int j = 0; j < img->h; j++)
        {
            m[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that your code is bogus, but i am suspecting this line:

```
SDL_GetRGB(getpixel(img, i, j), img->format, &sum, &sum, &sum);
```

any way, why you have to allocate a 2D array such way? why not just one continues block?

take a look to my code:

```
void integral_img(SDL_Surface * img)
{
    #define _IDX(x,y) ((x)+((y)*cx))
   int cx=img->w,
        cy=img->h;
    int *M;

    //allocating only one continues block of memory
    M = malloc(cx*cy * sizeof(int ));
    if(!M){
        perror("not enough memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    int sum_int = 0;
    Uint8 t sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cy; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cx; j++)
        {
            SDL_GetRGB(getpixel(img, i, j), img->format, &sum, &sum, &sum);

            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                sum_int = (int)sum;
            if (i == 0 && j > 0)
                sum_int = (int)sum + M[_IDX(i,j - 1)];
            if (j == 0 && i > 0)
                sum_int = (int)sum + M[_IDX(i- 1,j )];
            if (i > 0 && j > 0)
                sum_int = (int)sum + M[_IDX(i- 1,j )] + M[_IDX(i,j - 1)] - M[_IDX(i- 1,j - 1)];
            M[_IDX(i,j )] = sum_int;
        }
    }

    // easy to free
    free(M); 
    return;
}
```

it is cleaner and uses less iterations on allocating and freeing memory.